# What does "as intuitive as mud" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, simile

What does it mean when someone says, for example,

> That problem was "as intuitive as mud".

Comment: In the sentence "mud" is used metaphorically to mean "unclear". The meaning  is that  the problem was not intuitive, it was difficult to understand.

Comment: It's a paraphrase: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/as_clear_as_mud

Comment: Counterintuitive.

Comment: Can you reference where you found this phrase used? I think this is a poor analogy for whatever the author is trying to say. Clear as mud makes sense because mud is objectively opaque. Intuitive as mud is a stupid analogy because I have no baseline for whether mud should be intuitive or not. What does intuitiveness of an object even mean?? As intuitive as table. As intuitive as juice. Etc...

Comment: Can anyone suggest a better simile? Something familiar, and deeply counter-intuitive? A boomerang? A unicycle? Orbital mechanics?

Comment: That is a muddling of the phrase "as clear as mud", which means "not intuitive". As stated, your version is meaningless and is not in use.

Comment: Answers should keep in mind: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7221/13804

Comment: ...since you don't understand the expression, you could say it is _as intuitive as mud_!

Comment: I am just getting a kick out of how many people are griping that this phrase about unclarity is unclear, while also being able to describe what was meant.  It seems to me that whoever used this phrase has masterfully used a phrase that ends up being a demonstration of what it describes (whether this was done intentionally, or unwittingly).

Comment: @spacetyper I posted a question in the mathematics community and someone commented this phrase!

Comment: Whoever said "as intuitive as mud" should probably make like a tree and get out of here.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

That is a variation of the phrase "as clear as mud", which means "not clear at all".

Comment: Can't say I agree. It's a variation of the words, as in "clear" is changed to "intuitive", but it can't be an acceptable variation of the phrase as the meaning is lost.

Comment: @MichaelA-B Any (sarcastic) phrase of the form "as ... as mud" would be interpreted by most English speakers as being a variation of "as clear as mud", i.e. a negation of whatever property was being compared to mud.  In fact, it doesn't even need to be mud.  The phase "as useful as a chocolate teapot" is commonly used in the north of England to mean "useless".

Comment: @MichaelA-B I suspect it's deliberate irony, because the phrase itself becomes completely counter-intuitive once you substitute the word "clear".

Comment: @MichaelA-B The general concept here is what's often termed a "[snowclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone)": taking an established phrase and rephrasing it for a different context, even if it doesn't 100% fit. It's a relatively common process in modern English.

Comment: Exactly. "As clear as mud" is so widely known, when you substitute "as (blank) as mud", it pretty obviously means "not at all (blank)". Not to say that this type of substitution is common, but the meaning seems very clear to me.

Comment: @BradC: That's simply wrong. "as soft as mud" **certainly does not mean** "not at all soft".....

Comment: @user21820 Granted, the same is true for "as **brown** as mud", because *mud is actually soft and brown*. So if we had to define a rule, how about: when the adjective you put in there is *something that mud is obviously not* (clear, intuitive, tasty, thirst-quenching), then it's a variation of the ironic phrase.

Comment: @BradC: I'm not convinced it would be always understood by native speakers. In the case of "intuitive", especially for mathematics, it is clear that it is pretty much the same as "clear". But if you try telling native speakers that something is "as ironic as mud" or "as ridiculous as mud", I think they might think you're trying to be funny and yet be still unsure of your point. =)

Answer (score 28):

It means, not at all intuitive. The more common expression is:

***[(as) clear as mud](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-clear-as-mud):***
(humorous)
​

> very difficult to understand:
>   - *His instructions were as clear as mud.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I think you need to clarify.  "That problem was at all intuitive" doesn't parse very well and seems ambiguous.

Comment: @HotLicks - the problem was not intuitive at all!

Comment: @HotLicks It depends whether you get a round tuit or a square tuit ;)

Comment: I don't understand why voters haven't preferred this answer—which includes a citation and was posted two hours before the one-line, no-reference answer that (as I type this comment) currently leads it by 6 upvotes—to the currently more popular answer. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @SvenYargs Probably because the other answer contains the word "variation" which this one doesn't have. The other one may therefore be more, ehm, intuitive.

Comment: @Mr Lister - you mean that my answer is as clear as mud?

Comment: @SvenYargs, user66974 deleted the answer at 13.27 and then undeleted it at 16.41  by which time Editing Frank had already posted their answer, and not having 10K meant he could not see the deleted answer.

Comment: Of course user66974 could have clarified this by himself but chose not to.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Your comment about the time frame of activity helps clear the mud—at least with regard to how E.F.'s answer might have zipped past user66974's during the 3½ hours that the latter answer was deleted. Of course,  E.F.'s answer now leads user66974's by 22 votes, meaning that its advantage over this answer has increased by 16 votes since I wrote my comment (which came seven hours after user66974 had undeleted his answer). So either Mr Lister is correct that mentioning "variation" makes a big difference or a lot of voters upvote the first (or the shortest) correct answer they see.

Comment: @SvenYargs or maybe they saw the huge rep user66974 had at that time and chose to UV the "underdog". That's also a possibility, both answers are correct, this one has the dictionary citation but E.F's answer has the edge on the explanation part.

Answer (score 9):

I would have put this as a comment...

Unfortunately the phrase you quoted is a mangled idiom.
As other have pointed out - the phrase should read:
"(it is) as clear as mud."

Since mud is not noted for its "clarity" as it is opaque, it means that the topic under discussion is also not very clear, or is difficult to understand..

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as calling it mangled. Creatively extended is more like it. I imagine the speaker/writer was getting at the intuitiveness of something, and saying it was not at all intuitive by referencing the "clear as mud" cliché.

Answer (score 8):

This is obviously an echo of the phrase "as clear as mud", but it sounds very unnatural as it stands. To make it natural, it would have to be a response to somebody else's use of the word "intuitive". For example:

> Programmer: "The user interface was designed to be as intuitive as possible. Look, if you want to sort the rows, just press Ctrl-U."
>   User: "Intuitive as mud".

Answer (score -2):

If the phrase "as intuitive as mud" is used in a context related to software usage, software development, and user interface design, it might be a reference to [Multi-User Dungeon (MUD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) games. MUDs are games which are often entirely text-based, and played by typing commands.

MUD commands are sometimes hard to guess and even esoteric, based on the style of the game. For this reason something can be "as intuitive as MUD" (with or without uppercase acronym letters) for those who recognize the term. The metaphor means that *something is not intuitive*.

From [Wikipedia on MUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD):

> A MUD (/ˈmʌd/; originally Multi-User Dungeon, with later variants Multi-User Dimension and Multi-User Domain),[1][2] is a multiplayer real-time virtual world, usually text-based. MUDs combine elements of role-playing games, hack and slash, player versus player, interactive fiction, and online chat. Players can read or view descriptions of rooms, objects, other players, non-player characters, and actions performed in the virtual world. **Players typically interact with each other and the world by typing commands that resemble a natural language.**

(Emphasis mine.)

[image: Screenshot of the MUD1 game text interface (from 1987) played on a more modern Windows computer.]

Screenshot of the [MUD1 game from 1987](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD1) and its text interface, in this case accessed from/played on a more modern Windows computer.

Again from Wikipedia on MUD:

> The typical MUD will describe to you the room or area you are standing in, listing the objects, players and NPCs in the area, as well as all of the exits. To carry out a task the player would **enter a text command such as `take apple` or `attack dragon`**. Movement around the game environment is generally accomplished by entering the direction (or an abbreviation of it) in which the player wishes to move, for example typing north or just n would cause the player to exit the current area via the path to the north.[54]

(Emphasis mine.)

The repetitive command entry, as well as commands not always being obvious, lead to development of specific [MUD clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD_client) (sometimes third-party) which help the user by simplifying input. They were perhaps "clearer than MUD" ;)

Comment: Even as someone who used a MUD daily before, this didn't occur to me. I'm pretty confident fewer than 1 in 100 people even know what a MUD is. Absent any supporting context from the OP, this isn't a good explanation

Comment: I know exactly what a MUD is, but as you can see from what I just said, if you wanted to compare something's intuitiveness to a MUD, you'd say "intuitive as *a* MUD", and you'd also capitalize MUD. That's pretty clearly not remotely related.